# Power BI Check If Value Takes Place Before a Certain Time

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have data that looks like this:

```
Joined Time
null
null
10:01:00 AM
02:20:00 AM
```

I want to add a column that has the following logic:

```
If "Joined Time" < 09:00:00 AM then "PM"
if "Joined Time >= 09:00:00 AM AND "Joined Time" < 12:00:00 PM then "AM"
else null
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this? I am newish with doing complex stuff in PowerBI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power/M Query, create a new **Custom Column** whit this below code-

```
=
if [Joined Time] = null then null
else if [Joined Time] < Time.FromText("09:00:00AM") then "PM"
else if 
    [Joined Time] >= Time.FromText("09:00:00AM") 
    and [Joined Time] < Time.FromText("12:00:00PM") 
then "AM"
else null
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: Why does this code work? Why don't you get the "cannot convert null to type logical" error? I've played around with null values before, so I'm curious.

Comment: Hi @LunchBox, to avoid error "cannot convert null to type logical", you have to check the NULL as first logical test. Other cases, you will get that error.